# Write from Ultrawarm ES to DL ES

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have an application pumping logs to an AWS OpenSearch (Ultrawarm) cluster. I want to know what are the options to migrate the data from one UW elastic search to another.

Comment: "AWS OpenSearch (Ultrawarm) cluster" doesn't have any sense. What does it mean? You have a cluster with ultrawarm nodes? And do you want to migrate(one time process) your cluster or you want to send the logs to 2 clusters at the same time? Is your cluster aws managed or self?

Comment: I have a cluster with ultrawarm nodes and i want to migrate my cluster to another.and it is aws managed.

Comment: Your question still lacks information but I imagine you want to migrate from one account/region to another or one domain to another. Here is a guide, follow it and if you get stuck somewhere come back with more info so that people here can help you. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/opensearch-migrate-domain/

Comment: that helped much. Ill get back when i am into implementation.

Comment: i need one help with this. In the link in the document it had 'The easiest way of sending a signed request is to use the Amazon Web Services request signing interceptor . The repository contains some samples to help you get started, or you can download a sample project for OpenSearch Service on GitHub. ow-level Java REST client to perform two unrelated actions: registering a snapshot repository and indexing a document. You must provide values for region and host.'
.
What is the purpose of this step? can anyone explain?

Comment: Sorry for replying late. You can't make an anonymous request and aws wants you to identify yourself. That's why the signed request. Follow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/managedomains-snapshots.html#managedomains-snapshot-client-python.  You can also follow https://medium.com/docsapp-product-and-technology/aws-elasticsearch-manual-snapshot-and-restore-on-aws-s3-7e9783cdaecb for backing up your domain.

Comment: Okay. Actually my other concern is that i want to know how to migrate data from UW es to s3 in the source without impacting production. I found some ways but in that it said to restart the es server which is not feasible for me.

Comment: I don't know about such method but you cannot restart aws managed ES. You can send longs from the application directly to s3 along with ES. For example, you can send logs to both with fluentd in near real time.